# So, enhancement to smoke-detector suggested

Tags: feature-request

I suggested something in a conversation about [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20121983#20121983).
Basically, should we just farm "hot words" from things that are flagged, then if they're in below .01 of questions just add them to smoke detector?  It might make it a little less obvious and a little more false-positive.  Making it just learn though would be nice.

Comment: Perhaps someone could program in the ability to respond to Smoke Detector with a certain phrase that he could then parse and store - be it a False Positive, spam, offensive, etc. Obviously, that would be quite time-consuming, seeing as you're writing a program to find patterns in scattered responses-but not totally impossible. It could compare body text & title for key words.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness We already have that, restricted to a certain set of trusted users. We're working on a Bayesian algorithm for this, but it's not really ready.

Comment: @Undo Ah. Fair enough :)